# Conditional inclusion of sub-Makefiles based on ifeq test

Tags: makefile, include, conditional-statements

Is there a way to conditionally include a sub-Makefile based on the result of a an `ifeq` test as suggested below

```
CC = g++
CENTOS_VERSION := $(shell rpm -E %{rhel})   

TARGET = main

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).cpp
ifeq ($(CENTOS_VERSION),6)
    @echo "Building on CentOS 6"
    include(CentOS6_Makefile.mk)
else
    @echo "Building on CentOS 7"
    include(CentOS7_Makefile.mk)
endif
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).cpp
```

This does not work and generates the error message

```
Building on CentOS 6
include(CentOS6_Makefile.mk)
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `CentOS6_Makefile.mk'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `include(CentOS6_Makefile.mk)'
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

---

Based on the answer by @MadScientist the solution to my problem boils down to just 2 lines

```
CENTOS_VERSION := $(shell rpm -E %{rhel})
include CentOS$(CENTOS_VERSION)_Makefile.mk
```

Comment: Note, if someone runs this on CentOS 8 then it won't work (unless you have, which you didn't show in your question, a `CentOS8_Makefile.mk`).  That's why I put the ifneq in my solution, so that any "newer" version would use the `CentOS7_Makefile.mk` file, which is what your original code did.

Comment: @MadScientist I'm okay with it not working because I assume that a different Makefile would be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not related to `ifeq`; if you remove the `ifeq` and always include one or the other you'll see the same problem.

First, your syntax for including files is wrong.  There are no parentheses around filenames in make's `include` directive.  It should just be:

```
include CentOS6_Makefile.mk
```

Second, you cannot use makefile processor commands like `include` as part of a recipe (that is, indented by a TAB).  In a make recipe ALL lines that indented by TAB are passed to the shell as commands to run to build the target, they are not interpreted by make (except to expand macros).  Also, you cannot include some other makefile in the middle of a recipe: once make starts to include a new makefile that's the end of any recipe that is currently being defined.

You can do this:

```
CENTOS_VERSION := $(shell rpm -E %{rhel})   
ifneq ($(CENTOS_VERSION),6)
    CENTOS_VERSION := 7
endif

include CentOS$(CENTOS_VERSION)_Makefile.mk

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).cpp
        @echo "Building on CentOS $(CENTOS_VERSION)"
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).cpp
```